# raspberry pi3 BLE connecting issues

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, bluez

I'm trying to connect my Raspberry pi3 to my smart phone but it fails. On my RP I type the following command :

```
bluetoothctl
connect B8:08:D7:AC:CC:42
```

but I have the following error:

```
Attempting to connect to B8:08:D7:AC:CC:42
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

Is there someone who can help me?

Comment: Check the "journalctl -xe" log and share the error message if any regarding bluetooth. That helps further narrowing down the actual reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps. Before sharing the steps, share the logs from "`journalctl -xe`". If you see, "***a2dp-source profile connect failed for : Protocol not available***", then your R-Pi doesn't support or implemented A2DP profile. One quick option is to run the pulseaudio bluez module.

```
systemctl start bluetooth
hciconfig hci0 up
```

> > Switch on Bluetooth in your smart phone

```
bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# discoverable on
[bluetooth]# pairable on
[bluetooth]# scan on
>>> Wait for your device to appear during scanning process.
[bluetooth]# scan off
[bluetooth]# trust <Device MAC>
[bluetooth]# pair <Device MAC>
[bluetooth]# connect <Device MAC>
```

If you still see, 
***Attempting to connect to 44:D8:84:02:A3:17
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed***

Start the pulseaudio,

```
pulseaudio
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

Go back to bluetoothctl and try connecting again. But it's still possible for you to connect your phone to R-Pi without enabling the A2DP support just by connecting it from smartphone instead of R-Pi command line.

Comment: when i tried    pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover                       i had this error :                                                                                            Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused

Comment: make sure pulseaudio is running. Check with "ps -ef | grep pulseaudio". If pulseaudio is running fine, try loading module using "sudo"